# vscode can't find eslintrc.json

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, eslint

In my Angular project I'm receiving error on component names and a bunch of other stuff from eslint like this one:

`The selector should start with one of these prefixes: "app" (https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-02-07)eslint@angular-eslint/component-selector`

But in my `.eslintrc.json` I have this rule:

```
            "rules": {
            "no-console": "error",
            "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
                "error",
                {
                    "prefix": ["one"],
                    "style": "kebab-case",
                    "type": "element"
                }
            ],
            "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
                "error",
                {
                    "prefix": ["one"],
                    "style": "camelCase",
                    "type": "attribute"
                }
            ]
        }
```

So vscode clearly isn't using this eslint.
I already added the following line to vscode `settings.json` but it didn't work:
`"eslint.workingDirectories": ["./client"]`

Does anyone have any idea? I don't know if this makes a difference or not but I'm on Mac.

**Update** I also added the following line to `settings.json` but it's still not working:

"eslint.nodePath": "/Users/user-name/project-folder/project-name/client/.eslintrc.json",

**SOLVED** There was another eslintrc.json file somewhere in the project which was overriding this one.

Comment: where is your eslintrc file placed in your workspace folder?

Comment: inside client folder